# Find By Date Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, date, laravel, laravel-5

I have some problem with searching by existing date.

In Model:

```
$date = '2016-01-14';
public static function getByDate($date)
{
    $query = self::select('date', DB::raw('SUM(test_count) as test'))
        ->whereDate('date', '=', $date)
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
        ->get();
}
```

But I didn't get a result, because this code creates SQL:

```
select `date`, SUM(test_count) as test from `test_table` where date(`date`) = 2016-01-14 group by `date` order by `date` asc limit 1
```

Not quoted around of date => 2016-01-14

How to fix it?

I try to use whereRaw with params, for example:

```
return $query->whereRaw("date= ?",[$date]);
```

but it did not help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `->whereDate('date', '=', $date)` to this:

```
->where('date', '=', $date)
```

Or you can use this:

```
->whereDate($date)
```

So, it's obvious that, you can use either `->whereDate($date)` or `->where('date', '=', $date)` because `whereDate` is a dynamic method and in this case, it'll become: `where('date', '=', $date)`.